# Error importing shapely.set_operations in my python program

Tags: python, gis

A library I use has a line `from shapely.set_operations import union_all`. But when I run it, it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shapely.set_operations'`.

I tried installing a couple of older versions of shapely but no luck. I have got shapely version 1.7.0 on python 3.6. Installed it using pip.

Comment: Have you perhaps named your script (or some other script in the same directory) `shapely.py`?  *That* would be found by the `import` before the actual module.